# Change author and email address in Git

Tags: github

[image]I was changing the git author information inside the terminal and for whatever reason the update has removed the email from the commit and now I am unable to revert this change and can't add an email address to this commit.

The commit includes an author that I can't amend and the email linked to the commit is <>.

Can someone please advise how I can add an email address to this author?

[image]

Comment: Try using `git filter-branch` to do a batch edit for comments.

Comment: However, it seems you just came from a failed `git branch-filter` with unbalanced `"` and `'`s.

Comment: I did, is there a way to change the author name and re-add an email address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can batch change the commit history with the nuclear option `git filter-branch`. Using `--env-filter`, you can change author and email info. See [Changing Author Info - GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info) for more info. Since you don't have an email info now, you may catch the messy name for judging the necessity of rewriting.

For example,

```
#!/bin/sh
git filter-branch -f --env-filter '
OLD_NAME="Your messy name" # you may need to escape the " char in the head and tail of that messy
CORRECT_NAME="MatthewLRichardson"
CORRECT_EMAIL="preventing@email.spoiler"
if [ "$GIT_COMMITTER_NAME" = "#OLD_NAME" ]
then
    export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
if [ "$GIT_AUTHOR_NAME" = "#OLD_NAME" ]
then
    export GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="$CORRECT_NAME"
    export GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL="$CORRECT_EMAIL"
fi
' --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches --tags
```

Then, do a force push, and tell your collaborator to update their fork, if there exists some.